# Maths Or Islam?

Tags: quran

I am student the recently question comes into my mind that is

> does Islam depends on math or math depends on Islam

because according to my best observation i found that everything in our world depends on math

for example:

There are several places in Quran where math are used to describe the logic,
you can't do anything in world without math even in daily routine eat,walk and other stuff all includes math.

Comment: Could you give a definition of math please?

Comment: well there is no standard definition but i think whenever or wherever numbers get involved then we can say math is used there.

Comment: There's  no huge dependency between both. Usually Muslims rather need Maths than Islam would need it. And Maths don't need Islam. And saying that whenever or wherever numbers are involved we can say math is used is a very superficial definition Maths is much more abstract and numbers are only a small part of math and its application.

Answer (score 1):

Islam is submission to Allah. Math is the language of the Universe, created by Allah. Its just another tool to use in your life to fulfil your ultimate purpose of submitting your will to Allah.

Answer (score 1):

Allah is the Creator of everything. This not only includes things in the physical plane, but also things which are abstract and notions which exist in the metaphysical plane, and also other things of which we have no knowledge. He is the Creator of Mathematics as well. One of the names of Allah is Al-Muhsi which translates to The Reckoner, Appraiser,  or Accountant. Henry Bayman has [said](http://henrybayman.com/science-mathematics-and-sufism/) a concise meaning of it would be The Mathematician.

Now mathematics is essentially about abstract systems and deductions that can be drawn within these systems. Mathematical objects have no real existence, they are ideas that exist in the mind. Even that idea may sometimes be only a model of more underlying notion. When a shepherd counts 1,2,3 he may be using the notion of "one sheep", "two sheep", "three sheep" instinctively present in his mind. He is not bothered about any fancy abstract ideas.

So Mathematics is most certainly a part of creation, nothing more then that. However, it must be said that, as the Quran suggests that we should look for signs in the universe to learn more about Allah (Swt). It may be that knowledge of mathematics acquired properly will make us more cognizant of the order, discipline and justice of the laws prevailing physically and metaphysically around us and help us in knowing Allah better. Secondly, for practical reasons Imam Ghazali has said in his book, The Revival of the Religious Sciences, that knowledge of basic mathematics is fard-e-kifaya on the community. If no one has knowledge of basic mathematics in a city, trading and other activities will not be able to function properly, which will be harmful to the prosperity of the city.

Comment: you make me change my mind i asked wrong i should have to ask Quran depends on math or not.

Answer (score 0):

Islam means "submission to Allah".  You don't need math for this.

Comment: I am going to argue with you on that let see when we say Allah is 1, when we count 5 prayers and so many different math terms used in Quran but mostly numbers what do you say.

Comment: @shoaib sabir  numbers is not necessarily math. Animals like apes, dolphins, and even crows can count numbers. There is no abstract math involved.